# Read WhatsApp backup from Google Drive

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, google-drive

I can see WhatsApp Messenger in Google Drive.

> [image]

How can we read WhatsApp Messenger files from Google Drive backup? Does anyone know?

Comment: The last I time I read an answer, WhatsApp stored messages in databases and they are most likely encrypted. I don't think Drive provides any option to view a database let alone an encrypted one.

Comment: [The backup stored on Google Drive is actually not encrypted](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/163152/91904).

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK, **you cannot read those files** directly as they are encrypted and backed up on Google Drive.

The purpose of that Google Drive back up is to restore your chat history so that if you lose your phone or switch to another Android phone, your chats are safe.

Below is how you should **restore** back up of your chat history using Google Drive.

> - Make sure the same Google account that was used to perform the backup has been added to your phone.
> - Uninstall and reinstall WhatsApp.
> - After verifying your number, you will be prompted to restore your messages and media from Google Drive.
> - After the restoration process is complete, tap on Next and your chats will be displayed once initialization is complete.
> - After restoring your chats, WhatsApp will begin restoring your media files.

Note : **In order to successfully restore a Google Drive backup, you need to use the same phone number and Google account used to create the back up.**

You can read more on Google drive and WhatsApp Integration at [FAQ](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000019) page of WhatsApp.

Comment: but it did not restore my whatsapp status. :( I want to get my all status back... any other way?

Comment: did you used the same google account to restore which you used for back up? usually, WhatsApp first gets you chat history and then restore your media (provided you choose to take media back up)

Comment: "After restoring your chats, WhatsApp will begin restoring your media files." did not initiate on my end... The backup is almost 4 gigs so the photos and voice notes are definitely in there.

Comment: Turns out I had a WhatsApp folder with a Databases folder with a db file inside which caused WhatsApp to think Drive was not necessary, even though it said it was going to use Drive (but now that I've actually seen the process, it didn't even download).

Comment: **[not encrypted](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/163152/91904)**.

Answer (score 1):

Following [this (now deleted) Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/I-have-Crypt7-files-of-my-girlfriends-WhatsApp-How-can-I-read-her-messages) might solve the problem.
It's quite elaborate so I won't re-submit everything here. But basically this:

- Copy device database
- Copy device key
- Use a third-party viewer for WhatsApp