# Retrieving an old WhatsApp backup from Google Drive

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, google-drive

The phone was stolen and I would like to retrieve an old WhatsApp backup from Google Drive. I do not want the most recent backups offered, as these were since my phone was stolen.

I want an old one that is visible on Google Drive, but when I click it, the only options are to delete it or turn it off. I want to install it. This chat file is not visible in my WhatsApp/databases folder.

Answer (score 1):

[You can't access raw files of WhatsApp from Google Drive](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/138708/read-whatsapp-backup-from-google-drive?rq=1) (it is a hidden folder), and you can't choose which version you want to restore from (I cannot even see versions at my account).

But, you can try to restore the last backup from Google Drive, and then manipulate 
WhatsApp db files in order to delete some of your messages.
There are plenty of guides out there on how to decrypt WhatsApp db, after you decrypt it, delete the non-relevant messages and put the db back in your sd, Didn't try but it might works.